# 403 Forbidden with laravel in shared hosting

Tags: laravel-5, http-status-code-403

I've completed a project that i was working on, its a Laravel project,
and it's an application totaly separated, i have a page index.html with a link that anyone can click on to access to the application.
so i created a new file called **espace** and i placed all my project files there, also i put all laravel files in an other file called **client**, except the public file i placed all the files directly to the **espace** file.
Now, my probleme is that i keep getting 403 Forbidden error and that i cant acces to **mywebsite.com/espace** because i dont have the permission, i just dont know how i can solve this one ?
Thanks

Comment: are you create the .htaccess file right ?

Comment: i dont know how to create it, i'm using the default one with laravel